# Split a list by certain value until only the first element remains python

Tags: python

I would like to count how many times I can divide an array of elements by a certain value until only one element remains

An array of 10 elements can be divided by half 3 times, but my loop only does it one time and then stops. Clearly I'm missing something..

```
# a function that takes an integer as input
def split_a_list(length):
    
    # create an array of elements where the input to the function determines the length of the array
    elements = list(range(1, (length +1)))
    begin_index = 0
    end_index = len(elements)-1
    count = 0
    
    # a value that specifies the size of remaining size of the array
    divider = 2 
    
    while begin_index < end_index:
        # because divider = 2 (as defined above), this divides the array in half
        mid_index = math.floor(float((begin_index + end_index)/divider))
        
        # this counts the number of times the array has been divided
        count += 1
        
        # the last index of the array is now the mid index of the previous array
        end_index = mid_index - 1
        
        # here I would like the function to be called again, but with the integer corresponding to
        # the the updated end index which is the mid index of the previous array
        
        return split_a_list(end_index), count


# An array of 10 elements can be divided in half 3 times until 1 element remains
# I would like the function to store the number of times the array can be divided in the variable count 
# and return this value as output


length = 10
split_a_list(length)
```

This returns ((None, 1), 1) but I would like it to return 3 since an array of 10 can be divided 3 times until 1 element is left

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: "this returns nothing" - the code in your post returns `(1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 4)` when I run it

Comment: What does "split the list by a number < 1" mean?

Comment: separating an array doesn't use a split method. you use a loop to traverse the array.

Comment: it does `return` *something* but you are not doing anything with it. Try `print(split_a_list(length))`. Also fix your indentation and explain what your first code snippet is shown for.

Comment: I have updated post, I hope it is more clear now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only looking for an integer, just keep it simple use floor division.

```
length = len(your_list)
n = 0
while length > 1:
    length //= 2
    n += 1
```

The `//` operator (*floor division*) is used here to divide `length` into 2 (whole) parts. The result of the floor division is then assigned back to `length` and the operation continues until `length` is equal to `1`.

You can see it working here:

```
>>> length = 10
>>> length //= 2
5
>>> length //= 2
2
>>> length //= 2
1
```